# Multiple Forms On One View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Please forgive some of the messiness of the code. I'm trying to create a page that displays a text input, and gives multiple options to submit a post with different parameters while also passing the value of the text input for every item contained in a List. I pass a List to the view as a property of the ViewModel.

I have a For loop that iterates through the list generating an individual form for each item in the loop.

```
@for(int s =0;s<Model.stocklist.Count; s++)
{
using(Html.BeginForm("ProcessTransaction","MoveProductByInventory",FormMethod.Post))
{
           @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.stocklist[s].StorageLocation.Description)
    <span>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.stocklist[s].UnitCurrent)
    </span>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.tranamount)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.transunittype)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.trantypeenum)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.stocklist[s].StockID)
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add" id="btnadd" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Remove" id="btnremove"/>
}
}
```

The first iteration of the loop works perfectly, but for some reason the 2nd,3rd, and so on values are being passed back as null.

Specifically, the stocklist property contains Stock objects and is defined as follows:

```
        public List<Stock> stocklist { get; set; }
```

I am expecting the ViewModel.stocklist to contain the Stock object that pertains to whichever Submit button I am selecting on the page that was generated by an iteration of the for loop.

```
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.stocklist[s].StockID)
```

is generating the proper StockID values on the page for each loop iteration. For some reason the stocklist is not bringing the stock object when the specific form is submitted (other than the first iteration). It is throwing a null reference exception and the stocklist is null. When the first form on the page is submitted the stocklist is populated with the proper stock object.

Please let me know if there is a better approach to this, as this is kind of just what I came up with.

Thanks

Comment: What your doing could not post back except for the first form (and only only if the POST method had parameter `IEnumerable<YourModel> model`) because indexers must start at zero and be consecutive. Real question is why are you doing this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to create a quick way to input data for any record contained in the the stocklist that is passed to the view. The following image shows pretty much what I mean: http://imgur.com/Ec3R51D. Maybe I'll need to look at having a single form that iterates through all the stocklist items and then submit all values using only one submit button.

Comment: That would solve the issue and be a better user interface anyway. And you currently generating invalid html (lots of duplicate id's with `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.tranamount)`,`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.transunittype)` etc.) and lots of unnecessary controls which is just degrading performance.

Comment: That's what I'll go with. Thanks for the review.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible, you should use the lambda parameter of `___For` (in this case, `m`) within your lambda functions:

```
@for(int s =0;s<Model.stocklist.Count; s++)
{
    using(Html.BeginForm("ProcessTransaction","MoveProductByInventory",FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.stocklist[s].StorageLocation.Description)
        <span>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.stocklist[s].UnitCurrent)
        </span>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.tranamount)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.transunittype)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.trantypeenum)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.stocklist[s].StockID)
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add" id="btnadd" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Remove" id="btnremove"/>
    }
}
```

This should usually give the best result, and I believe it will solve your problem in this case.

As for the reason why, @TrueBlueAussie has provided an explanation below in the comments:

> The `DisplayFor` and other methods use reflection to pull apart the expression tree of the lambda expression to create the naming of the client side elements, so the context of the lambda expression has to match.

Comment: Correct, but you need to explain why this is required :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie To be honest, my understanding isn't deep enough to know exactly why this is needed. I know it has something to do with analyzing the expression and determining the property's location with respect to the model, but I don't know the exact reason beyond that. Any hints? :)

Comment: That is close. The `DisplayFor` and other methods use reflection to pull apart the expression tree of the lambda expression to create the naming of the client side elements, so the context of the lambda expression has to match.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks. :) I have added your explanation to my answer, but in [another comment section](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27601846/1945651), Stephen Muecke is telling me that the context doesn't matter (at least in a case like this), so I remain somewhat at a loss. :-/

Comment: Hmmm... I must admit my first thought was it made no difference... time to experiment methinks :)

Comment: Hi folks, @JLRishe I greatly appreciate your assistance and explanation. I have updated to use m => m.property instead of m => Model.property and am still receiving the null reference. I'll update the post up top to reflect the code as of current.